# How rotate cube around a sphere surface

Tags: 3d, rotation, geometry, java-3d

I want to put cubes around the sphere surface like:

### [image: cube arround sphere]

I'm using Java3D. I have a point of the sphere surface with:

```
    double s = (random.nextInt(360));
    double t = (random.nextInt(360));
    double radius = 180;
    double x = radius * Math.cos(s) * Math.sin(t);
    double y = radius * Math.sin(s) * Math.sin(t);
    double z = radius * Math.cos(t);
```

And I need put center of cube in this point and translate and rotate cubes like the figure.
How can I do this?

I try rotate with s and t in different axes. But there is my result:

[image]

### [image]

I need that the face of cube and the sphere surface are perpendicular like first image.

Comment: This is not fully specified how to rotate such cube, note that you can freely spin cubes around axis [x,y,z] - your displacement vector.

Comment: I'm not understand you but I need that the face of cube and the sphere surface are perpendicular.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution would be to do it in a sequence of 3 calls:

```
// having s,t,radius
// transform cube
GL11.glRotatef(s, 0, 0, 1);
GL11.glRotatef(t, 1, 0, 0);
GL11.glTranslatef(0, 0, radius);
```

If you need to calculate such matrix for use by your program, you can follow glRotate & glTranslate specifications how do they modify current matrix and replicate their behaviour. Alternatively you can query GL matrix after these operations using glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX);

Comment: Thanks for answer, but It not works for me. I did edited the question with images of your solution.

Comment: Try translation by [0,0,-radius], I'd also start with one angle set to 0.0 in order to detect if there is problem with another one.

Comment: @Anonymous I'm sorry but the original poster uses Java 3D, I don't understand why you provide an answer using another API even though it isn't wrong.